# How do i use a BinaryReader im getting error?

Tags: c#

I need ot read a binary file. But getting error. How can i do it ?
Im trying to explain what else can i write ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace BinaryReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form1
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void R()
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                // 2.
                // Position and length variables.
                int pos = 0;
                // 2A.
                // Use BaseStream.
                int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                while (pos < length)
                {
                    // 3.
                    // Read integer.
                    int v = b.ReadInt32();
                    Console.WriteLine(v);

                    // 4.
                    // Advance our position variable.
                    pos += sizeof(int);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

On this line im getting error:

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open)))
```

Error 'BinaryReader' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a name collision with your own namespace. Rename it, for example, to `BinaryReaderTest`, or use full name of `System.IO.BinaryReader` for the `System.IO`'s `BinaryReader` class:

```
using (var br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open)))
```

Comment: I just saw now that im also getting an error on the line: public partial class Form1 : Form1 on the first Form1 the error is: Error 1 Circular base class dependency involving 'BinaryReader.Form1' thats after i fix the using line did like in your example.

Comment: @DanielLip You should be inheriting from `Form`, not `Form1` (it does not make sense to inherit from your own class). You need to add `using System.Windows.Forms` at the top, and possibly add a reference to the .NET forms assembly (it's probably there if you started a project as a Windows application).